# I cannot understand how AJAX differ than normal HTTP methods in a practical way?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, http, crud

I know about all that stuff that AJAX for only reloading some parts of a web page without refreshing the whole page unlike HTTP have to refresh from all over again.

I created a TODO app to try the two different approaches:

Here is my HTML
There are two buttons `submit` for HTTP method post and `click button` for AJAX call

```html
<form id="todos" action='/addTodo' method='POST'>
  <input id="inputTodo" name='todo' />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Todo" />
  <input id="button" type="button" name="todoAjax" value="Add Todo Using AJAX" />
</form>
```

Here is my AJAX call

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let todo = {
      'todo': $('#inputTodo').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/addTodo",
      data: todo,
      success: function(todo) {
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And here is my back end handler for `post` request

```js
app.post('/addTodo', function(req, res) 
{
  var todo = req.body.todo;

  userModel.update({
    _id: req.user._id
  }, {
    $push: {
      todos: todo
    }
  }, function(err, done) {
    if (err)
      return err;
    return done;
  });
  res.redirect('/profile');
});
```

In both approaches i used to refresh the whole page to see the added TODO
using `res.redirect` on normal http method and `location.reload()` in AJAX method, should not the AJAX method have added the TODO without refreshing the page?

Comment: I'm not certain exactly what you're asking, but the HTTP requests from normal methods and AJAX are identical. The difference is in how the response is handled. In a normal request an entire HTML document is returned and loaded in to the browser. In an AJAX request, you should return *only* the content you want to update within *an existing* document (or a data structure you can use to update the current document, eg JSON or XML). The AJAX request also means the current page remains loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `location.reload()` in Ajax, you can add a div inside where you would wanna place content from your /profile using

`$('#todos').before('<div id="profile"></div>');`

Then hide the form using

`$('#todos').hide();`

And finally do

`$('#profile').load(todos.body.loc + '#idOfContentInProfilePage');`

Where in your app.post instead of res.redirect('/profile'), you can just do `res.end({"loc": "/profile"});`

If the profile page is a whole different page with full change in content and style, then you would wanna redirect instead.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is refreshing the page because you have `location.reload();` in the `success` method of the AJAX call.

Calling a `PHP` file with `AJAX` and by `Submit` button:

```js
$("#toDoAjax").click(function()
{
    var textToSend = $('#toDoText').value;

    $.post("locationOfPHPfile",
    {
        toDoText: textToSend
    },
    function(data, status)
    {
        alert("This is what I received: " + data + "\nWith Status: " + status);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="toDoText" id="toDoText" value="" placeholder="Enter here" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit with Submit" />
  <input type="button" id="toDoAjax" value="Submit with AJAX" />
</form>
```

In the PHP file:

```
<?php
    // For Submit button
    if(isset($_GET['toDoText']))
    {
        // Use proper escaping here like mysli_real_escape_string() if
        // your file is connecting to a MySQL database
        $clean['toDoText'] = $_GET['toDoText'];

        // Do something

        header('Location: /profile');
        // Always use exit() or die() if you don't want the rest of the
        // code executing after header()
        exit();
    }

    // For AJAX button
    if(isset($_GET['toDoAJAX']))
    {
        // Use proper escaping here like mysli_real_escape_string() if
        // your file is connecting to a MySQL database
        $clean['toDoAJAX'] = $_GET['toDoAJAX'];

        echo $clean['toDoAJAX'];
    }

?>
```